Classifying texts using word embeddings
I'm trying to train a model that is able to classify short texts (200-600 words per text). I got a training set with their corresponding labels, and a text might have one or more labels.
My first approach was to use TF-IDF with Naive Bayes but it wasn't performing very well. But after replacing Naive Bayes with a logistic regeression, the results improved a bit.
However, what are some of the more state-of-the-art methods that I could try? For example, can a text embedding model from OpenAI be of use? Compared to TF-IDF, embeddings would be able to handle synonyms, etc. But I'm struggling to put it all together, how should the vector (or vectors) for each text be calculated? It feels like embedding are better suited for sentence length classification or comparisons.

You might want to consider finetuning a transformers based model. If using python, there are a ton of open source pretrained models that you can use with huggingface. I would give DeBERTav3 a try. It would be beyond the scope of this comment or answer to fully explain how one of these models actually works, but in terms of the flow of data flow it would look like :-
Text vector -> Tokenizer -> Model Input.
Among other inputs (such as attention), a HF tokenzer will convert your text into smaller subwords (tokens), and then encode them into numbers based on an existing embedding matrix.
